# Hyperref + footnotebackref in longtable

Tags: tables, hyperref, cross-referencing, footnotes, longtable

While I'm aware that [hyperref](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) doesn't suport footnotes and I quote:

> hyperfootnotes     boolean    true
>   Makes the footnote marks into hyperlinks to the footnote text. Easily broken …

I'm wondering if anyone's found a workaround for something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[stable,perpage,multiple,bottom]{footmisc} 
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref} % connect note back to table
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext

\begin{longtable}{c c p{3cm} c}
  & centered \footnote{Here's a note from a
    centered column} & \\
  &  & paragraph \footnote{This note is } & \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Which gives[image]

Here we can see that the note from a centered column works as expected (i.e. clicking on the footnote label brings the user to the footnote' they can then click on *this* label and be brought back to the table) while that from a paragraph-formatted column is rather recalcitrant (it brings the user back to the top of the document). I'm using [footnotebackref](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/footnotebackref/footnotebackref.pdf) to get back to the table, but this behavior is not essential...

(I'm using the `\usepackage{}`s as above after numerous attempts to solve this - this seems to be the closest I can come).

I'm asking as I have a table spanning multiple pages which would be better if a paragraph-formatted column could hyperlink to a footnote on the same page.

Or is this currently not possible?

Comment: [recalcitrant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recalcitrant): *(Adjective) Marked by stubborn resistance to and defiance of authority or guidance.* Darn those paragraph footnotes...!

Comment: As posted I get an error `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \BackrefFootnoteTag ` you (or someone:-) should fix that before looking at the output. You don't say what is wrong with the output you show but I assume it is just the missing backlink on the second footnote, which is I assume related.

Comment: Thanks to you both. @David Carlisle I think the `\BackrefFootnoteTag` error is due to the second footnote not being properly defined and having no tag, so that `footnotebackref` can't find it. It can be removed by commenting out `\usepackage{footnotebackref}`

Comment: @dardisco yes you can comment out `footnotebackref` but then everything works and there is no issue, it is only that the backref doesn't work on the second footnot isn't it? If there are no footnote backrefs everythuing is as expected.

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes, I wish. It does compile without error. However  the backref is not the primary issue here. I'm afraid it still causes the same problem i.e. the footnote reference from the paragraph-formatted column still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some extra work is needed so that the corresponding tag used by `footnotebackref` is still available when it gets recalled. The following seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\footnote}{\edef}{\xdef}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \edef\@makefnmark{%
        \noexpand\mbox{\noexpand\textsuperscript{\noexpand\normalfont%
        \noexpand\hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\noexpand\@thefnmark}}}\noexpand\,}%
    \BHFN@OldMakefntext{#1}}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
    c
    >{\raggedright}p{3cm}
  }
  % start of table cells:
  centered \footnote{Here's a note from a
    centered column} \tabularnewline
  & paragraph \footnote{This note is from paragraph } \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, works like a charm, thanks! Will need to dig a little to see *how*...

Comment: @dardisco: Sorry, didn't put much explanation in! The tag is what `hyperref` uses as an anchor. The first patch converts `footnotebackref`'s setting of `\BackrefFootnoteTag` within `\footnote` to be global instead of lasting only for current group (`\xdef` instead of `\edef`), and the second part ensures that `\BackrefFootnoteTag` is expanded when `\@makefntext` is called rather than deferring it to when `\@makefnmark` is called (footnotes don't get created straight away when in a table but are saved for recalling later, but by then, multiple footnotes will cause earlier tags to get lost).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm still learning how to find function definitions.. I'm guessing you looked at source for `footnotebackref`, `hyperref` and functions `footnote` and `@makefnmark` to come up with this...

Comment: @dardisco: Yes, exactly. `source2e`/`latex.ltx` has the original forms of `\footnote` and `\@makefnmark` if needed. And also `longtable` changes footnote handling. `footnotebackref` is a very small package so I'd start with that. Just open up the `sty` file (either on your own machine or from CTAN if easier) and inspect! For specific commands, `latexdef` can be useful (and there's lots of questions and answers involving it on this site).

Answer (score 0):

@David Carlisle was bang on (as usual), it seems `footnotebackref` and `longtable` don't play well together. Here's a minimal example which produces the behavior I was originally hoping for.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

%\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
    c
    >{\raggedright}p{3cm}
  }
  % start of table cells:
  centered \footnote{Here's a note from a
    centered column} \tabularnewline
  & paragraph \footnote{This note is from paragraph } \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

giving (sorry for quality) [image]

Would be nice to have the `footnote` link back to the `longtable` so will keep this one open for now in case there's a way to do this.