# Clash between ASL class file and the cleveref and cite packages

Tags: hyperref, document-classes, cleveref, cite-package

I would like to submit a paper to the *Journal of Symbolic Logic*, which means that I need to use the Association of Symbolic Logic's class file `asl.cls` and bibliography style file `asl.bst`, both of which are available [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/).

In the past I've successfully used the `hyperref`, `cleveref` and `cite` packages together with both the `article` and `book` document classes. However, the class file `asl.cls` is causing trouble. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{asl}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={orange}}
%\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % If this is switched on, then the .tex file fails to compile.
\usepackage{cite} % This package doesn't lead to a catastrophic failure, but the citation appears as [?].

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\title{A minimal working example}
\author{M.W.\ Example}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{thm}\label{theorem}
There exists a solution to this \LaTeX{} problem.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
See the \TeX{} Stack Exchange.
\end{proof}

A reference to the theorem: \ref{theorem} This is working! :)

A citation: \cite{test} This is not working. :(

\bibliography{MWE}
\bibliographystyle{asl}

\end{document}
```

And here's the file MWE.bib:

```
 @article{test,
 author           = {Why, Y.O.},
 title            = {Clashes between packages and class files},
 journal          = {Journal of tricky \LaTeX{} problems},
 year             = {2017},
 volume           = {1},
 pages            = {1-101}
 }
```

Some observations and attempts so far:

1. The file `asl.cls` is from 2002, which I think predates some of the packages, but I couldn't find a more recent version.
2. I've looked through the file `asl.cls`, but my knowledge of the inner workings of LaTeX class files is **very** limited and there are so many dependencies I don't know where to start.
3. If I switch off the `cite` package, then the citation appears correctly as [1] (rather than [?]), but it's not clickable.
4. Some standard packages, such as `amsthm`, are built into the file `asl.cls` (not that I fully understand how).

So, my question is this: Is there a way to use the `hyperref`, `cleveref` and `cite` packages with (a possibly modified version of) `asl.cls`?

Comment: The `\newtheorem` definition should be done before `cleveref` is loaded such that `cleveref` can get grip of the new counter

Comment: The ASL class redefines `\cite` in a complicated way (see comments about line 5240) that is apparently incompatible with the `cite` package.  I'd suggest you avoid using the `cite` package with the ASL class.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Great tip. In previous files I've had both `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}` and `\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}` after `\usepackage{cleveref}`, but with `asl.cls` it seems that `\usepackage{cleveref}` should go in between.

Comment: @Thruston Also a great point. This still leaves open the question though of clickable citations with `asl.cls`.

Comment: @DanielWolf: `asl` seems weird. I have no clue for the clickable issue however. Perhaps switching to the highly `biblatex` is the better option instead of using the strange `\cite` command by `asl`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I will try `biblatex`, although I'm slightly worried that might then clash with `asl.bst`!

Comment: @DanielWolf: Oh, I am pretty sure that it will **clash** with `asl.bst`;-) But I believe that the `ast.bst` style is done with `biblatex` already, perhaps with a different name, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've poked around the files `asl.cls` and `asl.bst` and tried to make sense of the document class's user guide (in `asldoc.ps`).

- Make a copy of the file `asl.cls` and call the copy, say, `als-mod.cls`.
- Open the file `als-mod.cls` in text editor and go to line 3332, where the (re)definition of `\bibliographystyle` begins. Comment out the entire (re)definition of this macro, i.e., lines 3332 to 3349.
- In your main tex file, specify `asl-mod` as the required argument of `\documentclass`, and specify the options `bibother` and `otherbib` -- yes, both of these!
- In your main tex file, change the argument of `\bibliographystyle` from `asl` to `plain`. The coding in the file `asl.bst` is simply beyond the pale. No point in trying to fix it. The user guide of the `asl` document class suggests, albeit indirectly, that it's acceptable to compile one's bibliography using the `plain` style; go for it! (The user guide states that "there is no reason to use a style other than `asl`." While this does sound like an endorsement of using the `asl` bibliography style, there is no indication that one has to use `asl`.)

With these changes, `\cite` instructions will actually give you numeric citation call-outs. Woo-hoo!

- To get `cleveref` to work, be sure to (a) run `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}` *before* loading `cleveref` and (b) provide the instruction `\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}` after loading `cleveref`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@article{test,
 author       = {Why, Y. O.},
 title        = {Clashes between packages and class files},
 journal      = {Journal of tricky \LaTeX{} problems},
 year         = {2017},
 volume       = {1},
 pages        = {1-101}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[otherbib,bibother]{asl-mod} % not 'asl'
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor={blue},
            citecolor={red}}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % 'nameinlink' option is optional
\crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\bibliographystyle{plain} % not 'asl'

\begin{document}
%\title{A minimal working example}
%\author{M.W.\ Example}
%\maketitle

\begin{thm}\label{theorem}
There exists a solution to this \LaTeX{} problem.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
See the \TeX{} Stack Exchange.
\end{proof}

A \verb+\cref+ cross-reference: \cref{theorem}. This is now working.

A citation call-out: \cite{test}. This now works too.

\bibliography{MWE}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried to shift the `\newtheorem` usage before `cleveref` is loaded?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I did. If one does this, there are not outright error messages. Unfortunately, the output of `\cref` consists of an unappealing **[??]** :-(

Comment: Really. I was sure that it worked this morning without [??]....

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Many thanks for double-checking! Indeed, there was a typo in my code that made me believe one couldn't get `cleveref` to work. Upon fixing the typo, it does appear to work OK. :-)

Comment: Fortunately I never generate typos ;-) (Ok, that's a lie :D)

Comment: @Mico Great solution. Many thanks for really looking under the hood.

Comment: @Mico @ChristianHupfer I just came across another issue: The ASL class file seems to clash with the `footnotebackref` package. When I try to use said package I get the error message `\@makefnmark undefined`. I tried some proposed solutions, e.g. [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137594/hyperref-footnotebackref-in-longtable) by @cyberSingularity, but to no avail. (I'm not sure if the forum rules dictate that I should post this as a new question, but with all the backstory it seemed easier this way.)

Comment: @DanielWolf - Thanks. Given that the matter of footnotes didn't come up in your original posting and that there was no hint as to the fact that you'd like to use the `footnotebackref` package, it would indeed be preferable if you created a new query. Just be sure to lay out to your readers what you've done so far, the issue(s) you've encountered, and what you would like to achieve.