# Clash with footnoteref and amsart class file

Tags: footnotes, amsart

I'm writing an article with the class file `amsart`. (Well, I'm actually using a modified version of the ASL class file -- see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367453/clash-between-asl-class-file-and-the-cleveref-and-cite-packages) -- but `amsart` requires less effort for people reading this question to use and is hopefully similar enough.) I want to use `footnotebackref` but the unnumbered footnotes generated by `\thanks`, `\keywords`, etc. are causing an issue: I get the error message `LaTeX Error: \@makefnmark undefined`. I presume the issue is that they're foonotes but without footnote markers in the main body of text and so `footnotebackref` doesn't know where to link back to.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\title{A problem with footnotebackref and amsart}
\author{Foo T.\ Note}
\thanks{My heartfelt thanks go to the TeX Stack Exchange.} % If you comment out this line, ...
\keywords{footnotebackref, amsart} % ... this line and ...
\subjclass{001} % ... this line, then the error no longer occurs.

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This is a great place for a footnote.\footnote{Where did this footnote come from? Click on the footnote number to see!}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During `\maketitle` processing, `\@makefnmark` is undefined, so the `\renewcommand` done by `\@makefntext` (when `footnotebackref` is loaded) fails.

There is another place to act on, otherwise the `\thanks` would not appear.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\makeatletter
% this can be done with xpatch
\xpretocmd{\@adminfootnotes}{\let\@makefntext\BHFN@OldMakefntext}{}{}
% this would be harder, so better copying the code from footnotebackref
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{@makefnmark}
    {}
    {%
     \renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
       \mbox{%
         \textsuperscript{%
           \normalfont
           \hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\@thefnmark}%
         }%
       }\,%
     }%
     \BHFN@OldMakefntext{#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\title{A problem with footnotebackref and amsart}
\author{Foo T. Note}
\thanks{My heartfelt thanks go to the TeX Stack Exchange.}
\keywords{footnotebackref, amsart}
\subjclass{001}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is a great place for a footnote.\footnote{Where did this 
  footnote come from? Click on the footnote number to see!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works wonderfully with `amsart`! But alas my hope that `amsart.cls` and `asl.cls` are similar enough with regard to `footnotebackref` was too optimistic: If you try the modfied MWE with `asl-mod.cls` from @Mico in the [motivating question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367453/clash-between-asl-class-file-and-the-cleveref-and-cite-packages) then unnumbered footnotes do not appear.

Comment: @DanielWolf For `asl.cls`, it should be `\xpretocmd{\@maketitle}` instead of `\xpretocmd{\@adminfootnotes}`.

Comment: Nothing short of amazing. Many thanks indeed. This issue had been bugging me for some time.