# Issue with ASL class file and equation numbering/referencing

Tags: hyperref, cleveref

This is a (delayed) follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367453/clash-between-asl-class-file-and-the-cleveref-and-cite-packages). I am having two issues with equation numbering and referencing when using the ASL class file:

**Issue 1** Despite the command `\nonumber` in the definition of `equation*` in the class file, the equation counter is counting them. I'm at a loss as to how to solve this.

**Issue 2** `\Cref` is not working with equation references. The usual commands `\ref`and `\eqref` work okay, but I like the fact that when you use `\Cref` both the number *and the brackets* are clickable. I have a partial solution:

```
\def\myeqref#1{\href{#1}{\color{mylinkcolour}(}\ref{#1}\href{#1}{\color{mylinkcolour})}}
```

However, while the brackets are clickable, clicking on them doesn't actually send you anywhere.

Here's a MWE, where `asl-mod` is the modified class file, as suggested by @Mico in the [original  question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367453/clash-between-asl-class-file-and-the-cleveref-and-cite-packages):

```
\documentclass[reqno]{asl-mod}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{mylinkcolour}{blue!55!black}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor={mylinkcolour}}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\def\myeqref#1{\href{#1}{\color{mylinkcolour}(}\ref{#1}\href{#1}{\color{mylinkcolour})}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
x = x
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation}\label{test}
y = y
\end{equation}

\texttt{ref}: \ref{test} % Sends you to the wrong equation.

\texttt{eqref}: \eqref{test} % Sends you to the wrong equation.

\texttt{cref}: \cref{test} % Doesn't work at all.

\texttt{Cref}: \Cref{test} % Doesn't work at all.

\texttt{myeqref}: \myeqref{test} % Almost what I want!

\end{document}
```

My apologies if it's against the forum rules to put two issues into one question. I bundled them together because they might have related solutions. They're certainly related in a functional sense.

Comment: For the first issue, an obvious solution would be to use the standard `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: Could you post a link to this class?

Comment: That is an extremely good point. For some reason I was under the impression that one should avoid using `\[ ... \]`, but I was confusing that with `$$ ... $$`. As for the class file `asl.cls`, it can be found [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/). You'll need to implement the changes suggested by @Mico in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367453/clash-between-asl-class-file-and-the-cleveref-and-cite-packages) to get it to work with `cleveref`.

Comment: @DanielWolf: Well, it would be better to provide at least a link to the modified class - I don't want to perform the edits Mico proposes and doing the job again then.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Yes, you're absolutely right. The file `asl-mod.cls` can be found [here](http://www.dwolf.eu/uploads/2/7/1/3/27138059/asl-mod.cls).